# Find the formula for a derivative

Tags: calculus

Suppose: $$n(x)=\frac{1}{x}+1$$

Find $n'(x)$

The book indicates the answer is: $$\frac{-1}{x^2}$$ However I am not sure how it got that conclusion. Would anyone mind walking me though the problem step by step?

Comment: You know that you can differentiate $n(x)$ term by term, and that the derivative of the constant term is $0$, so it all comes down to differentiating $\frac1x$. But $\frac1x=x^{-1}$; can you finish it from there yourself, using the power rule?

Comment: Rewrite $1/x$ as $x^{-1}$. Use the power rule. Then rewrite again. $1$ is a constant so its derivative is zero.

Comment: What is the definition of a derivative that you are using?  Do you want a rigorous proof or just a computation?

Comment: @Goos computation should suffice as it just states to find a formula algebraically.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yeah I went back into the book and reread about the power rule. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Bob: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(Hints)**

- You can write $\frac1x + 1 = x^{-1} + 1$
- The derivative of $x^{-1} + 1$ is the same as the derivative of $x^{-1}$ plus the derivative of $1$
- The derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ for any $n $
- What is the derivative of a constant?

Comment: Thanks, makes more sense now as $-1x^{-1-1}$ ends up equaling $\frac{-1}{x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate it term by term, and I think you know that the derivative of 1 is 0 because 1 is a constant value, so, now differentiating 1/x. You can use two methods either you use quotient rule by making u=1, du=0 and v=x, dv=1, then use the quotient formula to get the answer OR use this second method, firstly, change 1/x to inverse of x,  then use the power rule to get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Calculus Tricks:

$( f + g) ' = f' + g' $

$ (x^t)' = tx^{t-1} $

$( C )' = 0 $ where $C$ is a constant.

With this tricks, you can easily solve your problem.